# android java URLDecoder problem

Tags: android

i have a String displayed on a WebView as  "Siwy & Para Wino"

i fetch it from url , i got a string "Siwy%2B%2526%2BPara%2BWino".     // be corrected

now i'm trying to use URLDecoder to solve this problem :

```
String decoded_result = URLDecoder.decode(url); // the url is "Siwy+%26+Para+Wino"
```

then i print it out , i still saw  "Siwy+%26+Para+Wino"

Could anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation (of URLDecoder)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html):

> This class is used to decode a string which is encoded in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME content type.

We can look [at the specification](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1) to see what a `form-urlencoded` MIME type is:

> The form field names and values are escaped: space characters are replaced by '`+`', and then reserved characters are escaped as per [URL]; that is, non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by '`%HH`', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks, as in multi-line text field values, are represented as CR LF pairs, i.e. '`%0D%0A`'.

Since the specification calls for a percent sign followed by two hexadecimal digits for the ASCII code, the first time you call the `decode(String s)` method, it converts those into single characters, leaving the two additional characters `26` intact.  The value `%25` translates to `%` so the result after the first decoding is `%26`.  Running decode one more time simply translates `%26` back into `&`.

```
String decoded_result = URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.decode(url));
```

You can also use the [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) class if you have UTF-8-encoded strings:

> Decodes '%'-escaped octets in the given string using the UTF-8 scheme.

Then use:

```
 String decoded_result = Uri.decode(Uri.decode(url));
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks for all answers , i solved it finally......

solution:

after i used URLDecoder.decode twice (oh my god) , i got what i want.

```
String temp = URLDecoder.decode( url); //      url = "Siwy%2B%2526%2BPara%2BWino"
String result = URLDecoder.decode( temp ); // temp = "Siwy+%26+Para+Wino"

// result =  "Swy & Para Wino". !!! oh good job.
```

but i still don't know why.. could someone tell me?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include background on the reason this works.