# How to create Android Uri with hashtag in the center

Tags: android, uri, urlencode, hashtag, uribuilder

I have the following Uri I want to construct.

```
https://www.example.com/sub/#/action?firstparam=123456&secondparam=abcdef
```

I use the Android [Uri.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder) to construct the Uri

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme(HTTPS_SCHEME).authority("www.example.com").appendPath("sub").appendPath("#").appendPath("action")appendQueryParameter(
            "firstparam", first).appendQueryParameter("secondparam", second).build();
```

But the hashtag is encoded and will result in the following Uri

```
https://www.example.com/sub/%23/action?firstparam=123456&secondparam=abcdef
```

How to prevent this? I tried using `fragment` but it adds the hashtag at the end of the Uri.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818568/android-java-urldecoder-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how Uri.Builder works. It encodes non-safe URL characters with special meaning to their hex values. In your case `#` is encoded as `%23`

To prevent this use:

```
builder.appendEncodedPath("#")
```